# how to set when downloading from playstore that app should install in sdcard or internal memory in android?

Tags: android

Requirement: When I install app from the playstore,after clicking on install button I  want  to  show a  dialog whether  app should   be  installed in  SD card or internal memory.  How  can  I  achieve this. Can someone  help   me  out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)'s `android:installLocation`.

Dynamically changing the `android:installLocation` is not possible.

Comment: that won't display a dialog to ask where to install it

Comment: Yes  Yu are  right  Tim.  Help  me out how   to  do

Comment: Is  it  possible  to  open  dialog  also ?